# Update a single value of a 2d tensor using pytorch scatter without simple assignment operation

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to achieve the simple functionality with pytorch scatter. Using pytorch scatter, update a value in tensor for a given index.

I am hoping for something like this.

```
#not working code, but an idea 

import torch
target = torch.ones((20,20))
index = torch.tensor([(5,3)])
value=6
target.scatter(0, index, value)
```

The expected outcome is

```
target[5][3] is 6
```

Note the same can be done easily in TF with **scatter_nd_update**

Comment: Why do you not want to use assignment?